# Is there any benefit to using the same Pokemon all the time, increasing the 'battles won' statistic?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a Gengar which I use a lot. Should I use other Pokemon more, or does sticking to one Pokemon bring additional benefits?

For example, am I increasing the likelihood of getting Gengar candies on Pokemon gyms? or do I become a better Ghost-type trainer? Does it increase my likelihood of catching Ghost Pokemon (by either modifying the catch rate or making it appear closer to me)?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any benefit to use the same Pokémon all the time.

If you have a Pokémon with better moves / IVs / level, then it will be better than your current one, no matter its "Battles Won" number.